# Display a video in the email body in SAP Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a requirement where I need to display a video in the email body. I have the video url (in mp4 format) available and I am sending it to the velocity template from the Context class.
I tried iframe and video controls (html5) but none of them work.
Any one having any idea ?

Comment: What is rendered in the email? Are you testing from your local environment or CCV2 environments?

Answer (score 1):

This problem isn't just part of hybris problem. Email clients has limitations to show videos in an email.

You can check supported email clients and techniques at this [link](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/a_how_to_guide_to_embedding_html5_video_in_email/).

Comment: Thankyou .. the link was helpful to understand. Although I tried with video controls and it’s not coming proper. With img src thumbnail is coming broken on email page.